# java indexer in eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project in Eclipse and am using CDT.  The same project has java source code files within it.  If I try to open a declaration on java code, I get an error "Problem opening an editor: Reason [project] does not exist".  The declaration appears in a java source file in the project.

Opening a declaration with C++ code works

I tried to rebuild the index, and double-checked that the source location in Preferences->C++ General -> Paths and Symbols is correct.

Thanks in advance.